# Is there way to cache material-ui styles?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/) in React app with SSR. In [reciepts](https://material-ui.com/guides/server-rendering/#reference-implementations) it's said that I should collect all stylesheet data and insert it `<head>`.

Such approach will not support caching, because I don't want to cache html page itself. So my question is: is there way to use material-ui styles in way, which will enable caching, like putting all css data to separate file?